# JMETER Login Error. The target server failed to respond

Tags: authentication, jmeter, load-testing

We are testing a webpage process from login to logout using JMeter. Using 200 users we only logged in 160+ users and the remaining users didn't get through. Here is the result on Sampler Result page:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-149

Sample Start: 2013-05-27 11:42:35 CST

Load time: 60549

Latency: 0

Size in bytes: 1845

Headers size in bytes: 0

Body size in bytes: 1845

Sample Count: 1

Error Count: 1

Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException

Response message: Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond



Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:

ContentType: 

DataEncoding: null
```

Please help. We are stuck here for almost 2 weeks.

Comment: Add screen shots of the jmeter

Comment: The Unlucky, screenshot here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1ny.jpg

Comment: Elaborate the steps u which followed :) What was the response u used to get normally ?

Comment: This is the response i get for successful login. is this what you are asking for? im really new on this. Thread Name: Thread Group 1-22 Sample Start: 2013-05-27 18:13:09 SGT Load time: 33040 Latency: 33040 Size in bytes: 2660 Headers size in bytes: 330 Body size in bytes: 2330 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 0 Response code: 200 Response message: OK

Comment: Response headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: JSP/2.2
Server: Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=579fca70048e15c6f3832e9cab3c; Path=/RemoteBankingFE; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 2330
Date: Mon, 27 May 2013 10:12:57 GMT

Comment: HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
DataEncoding: ISO-8859-1

Comment: i Can suggest you that start your load test from 1 increase it variably and find out the load balance that the db server how much it can handle it in the 1 Ramp Up time ? DB server  might get down for 160 users , Here threads are not in sequence its mutually runs dynamically , keep track of load based on the Ramp Up time's

Comment: Does the ramp up time matters even if i only have 1 thread? i played with the properties in HTTP request per page and my logged in users goes up to 210 out of 300. i still get pages with errors of "Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond". and some of the failed pages have a "response code 500"

Answer (score 0):

This might indicate your server cannot handle additional load.

Also check that all your users are fine by running a test on all `csv` dataset

Also you have a `ramp-up` of `0` in thread group, you should have something higher.

Comment: is this nothing to do with the setup of jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

this is nothing related to your Jmeter installation. This error indicates your server is not able to respond when you have put enough load on it, or server is taking much time to respond. You can also try increasing the retries and timeouts.
To do this, edit the **jmeter.properties** file for **retries = 3** and **timeout = 120**. Make sure to delete the #s at the start of the lines or they will remain commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the solution was to change the **requests Implementation** to **JAVA**.

Comment: I seem to face the same situation. HttpClient 4 and 3.1 get few hundred of `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException` (this happens during scaling). With Java implementation there are no errors. Did you find out what's the difference?